# Spark seems to scale vertically, without no configuration effort

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I did an install of `Hadoop 2.7.2` single node, almost manually following tutorial on internet, then almost manually I even installed Spark, starting from `spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`, a version that claims to work with hadoop 2.6+.
I did no effort to configure Spark, just started to use it with interactive python: it worked immediately, that is a little surprising too, but anyway...
Then I decided to run an example in order to see if it scale properly vertically. My box as 4 CPU, so i decide to run an easy to parallelize job, ie the PI computation: http://spark.apache.org/examples.html.
Surprisingly, the result is this one ( the box is an old 4 core ):
[image]
and, from the PySpark console:
[image]
It seems to me that it scale perfectly on the 4 cpu cores I have.
Problem: I did not configure number of cores, and I don't know why, this is a typical behavior that will not work in production, and would be hard to explain what to configure. Is there some YARN/SPARK feature that automatically scale to the cores available?
Then, other question, is this using YARN? How can I understand if my Spark leverages YARN a s a cluster manager?

Comment: _Is this using YARN_ - no it doesn't. In a local mode Spark by default is using `local[*]` or in other words starts a number of threads equal to the number of available cores. Other than that behavior differs between different cluster managers. Standalone mode will work more or less the same way as a local mode but beyond that available configuration and default parameters will vary from manager to manager.

Comment: @zero323 with a little more elaboration about what to change to run with yarn, post this answer and I will accept.

Comment: reason for close and downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I have to confess I voted to close as to broad.  It is really interesting question but with multiple pages of documentation alone it is really hard to write something that fit into SO format. Regarding YARN you can can take a look at  [How-to: Tune Your Apache Spark Jobs (Part 2)](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/). Personally I don't feel comfortable enough with YARN to answer.

Comment: With PySpark there is also a matter of Python side  and JVM side code and depending on the API you use execution can be switch between these two.

Comment: I must confess that this is an interesting topic @zero323 and most of the documentation related to tuning a cluster is very very confuse. Specially when the nodes are asymmetrical.

Comment: Are you running examples through Spark-Shell?

Comment: @PankajArora with the IPython shell

Comment: I am not too familiar with Ipython shell but if you somehow set property spark.master yarn-cluster you will be able to use yarn.

Also you can see Spark UI at localhost:4040 and under environment tab check all the properties which are set.

Under executor tab you can see how many executors are launched for your job and how tasks are assigned to them.